# How to automatically verify code follows defined coding standards

Tags: java, static-code-analysis

The project I work on has a couple of internal coding standards such as (e.g.):

- domain classes have `toString()`, `hashCode()` and `equals()` defined
- domain classes have all the attributes `final`
- constructor injection is used instead of field or setter injection

Is there a tool allowing to define the above rules and enforce them at build (failing the build if there are violations of the above rules)?

Comment: CheckStyle wouldn't work? Since it's the obvious first choice.

Comment: as Marko said, [CheckStyle](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) is the first choice, and you can add it to your test suit to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SonarQube for finding the code quality for which you can look [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/).

You can also add/customise rules in SonarQube according to your project needs along with the provided rules by SonarQube.